# How to discover other domain hosts using rtps_discovery

Tags: ssl, network-programming, opendds

Recently, I try hard to use OpenDDS SSL in WAN network. But All my attempts to failed.
This is caused by the inability to find different hosts.
I realized one thing. OpenDDS security should use rtps_discovery, not InfoRepo, and it is difficult to find two hosts in different subnetworks via rtps_discovery.
I have been searched about discovering host by rtps_discovery option from SourceForge, github, and stackoverflow. But, No one successed in this manner.

https://sourceforge.net/p/opendds/mailman/message/36320180/

https://github.com/objectcomputing/OpenDDS/issues/854

So, my question is how to find the host using rtps_discovery on the WAN network.

here is my ini file:

```
[common]
DCPSGlobalTransportConfig=$file
DCPSSecurity=1

[domain/4]
DiscoveryConfig=uni_rtps

[rtps_discovery/uni_rtps]
SedpMulticast=0
ResendPeriod=2
SpdpSendAddrs=publisher's IP:56789

[transport/the_rtps_transport]
transport_type=rtps_udp
use_multicast=0
local_address=subscriber's IP:55555
```

please give me some ideas to solve this problem
It is really impossible to discover hosts in different subnetworks via rtps_discovery??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm finally success to communicate using rtps discovery!
It just SpdpSendAddrs attribute set 8410 port.
like this:

```
[common]
DCPSGlobalTransportConfig=$file
DCPSSecurity=1

[domain/4]
DiscoveryConfig=uni_rtps

[rtps_discovery/uni_rtps]
SedpMulticast=0
ResendPeriod=2
SpdpSendAddrs=subscriber's IP:8410

[transport/the_rtps_transport]
transport_type=rtps_udp
use_multicast=0
```

But, new question is that how to confirm this security function work properly??
When I capture packet by wireshrk, I can see the data not encryped.
I used OpenDDS Messenger security example.